# How to add server certificate, which I trust, in postman for 2 way TLS?

Tags: postman, ssl-certificate, truststore, tls1.3

I have added my client certificates in postman by going to FILE > SETTINGS > CERTIFICATES > *CLIENT CERTIFICATES SECTION*.

Where do I add the server certificate, which I trust, for 2 way TLS?

There is a section above *Client certificates* called *CA Certificates*. Is this where the trusted certificate is to be added?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Client certificate needs to go to Client Certificates. This will be your keystore.

Server certificate needs to go to CA Certificates. This will be your truststore.

See the docs [here](https://blog.postman.com/encryption-ssl-tls-and-managing-your-certificates-in-postman).

Comment: The doc doesn't say anything about *CA Certificates* being the place where we store server certificate.

Comment: You can either trust root CA cert, which is a typical scenario, or for test purposes you can add there leaf / end entity / server cert.